# k-rotated-shifted array and finding x?

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, data-structures, binary-search

We say a `k-rotated-shifted array`, to an array such that with k rotate can be sorted.  Example is : `A=[10, 15, 20, 1, 7]`, with `k=2`. I propose an algorithm for finding a key like `x` in this k-rotated-shifted array.

anyone could help me to verify it?

[image]

Edit 1: my new code is:

```
 int S(int l, int r, int x)
{ int f=A[l], m=A[(l+r)/2], la=A[l];
if (x==f or x==m or x==la)
     return 1;
else {if ((x< f and x>m) || (x>f and x>m) || (x<f and x<m))
   return S((l+r)/2, r, x);
   else
    return S(l,(l+r)/2, x);
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Breaks finding 1 in 3,4,5,1,2. Breaks finding a key that is not present, because the base case triggers only when the key is found, causing an infinite loop.

To fix, use the condition

```
first < middle < x or middle < x < first or x < first < middle.
```

Also note that comparing with `last` is superfluous if we take the ceiling of `(i + j) / 2`.

Comment: i couldent get it. why my condition failes?

Comment: @Prof.KosiNoura Works but takes time O(log^2 n).

Comment: this main code is works on O(log n)? just need correct the condtion?

Comment: wait. if i add these condition on one line, what is the last line else used for?

Comment: it's okey, but please say why when x is not in the array, it falls on infinite loop

Comment: is it possible to answer to my last question? then I  Approve it.

Comment: @Prof.KosiNoura Because you're not handling the base case when `i == j`.

Comment: @beaker, is it possible wrote the condition as a new answer to approve?

Comment: It's not really a full answer on its own, since it doesn't fix your logic. @DavidEisenstat is free to add it to his answer, though.